# Mapping with Layers in GeoPandas and Matplotlib: Issue is I cannot set the desired fig size

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, geopandas

Idea is to plot in layers having a base map(r5_base) and then overlay by gpd a 'regionbybranch'.

As can be seen from images below, two figures were created but I am expecting only one. The desired map was plot correctly with the second figure but it did not follow the desired 'figsize'

```
# Isolate Region on map 
r5_base = bars[bars.Reg_Name=='REGION V (BICOL REGION)']
# Isolate region from OP data
region=mpabars_gdf[mpabars_gdf.RegionName=='Bicol Region']

# Plot area.
regionbybranch = region.dissolve(by='BranchName', aggfunc='sum',as_index=False)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,sharex=True, sharey= True, figsize=(30,30))
base = r5_base.plot(color='gray')

regionbybranch.plot(ax=base, linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='black', legend= False, column='Penetration',cmap='viridis')

# plt.title('Market Penetration on Bicol Region');
# fig.savefig(“map_export.png”, dpi=300)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set the proper axes name when you call the plot function. Something like this should work:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,sharex=True, sharey= True, figsize=(30,30))
base = r5_base.plot(ax=ax,color='gray')

regionbybranch.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='black', 
            legend= False, column='Penetration',cmap='viridis')
```

Comment: yes, this works perfectly... however I still do not understand clearly why it did not work the first time.

Comment: because you were basically calling different subplots/figures. When you create a figure and subplot with `fig, ax = plt.subplots(...) ` you are also giving them a _name_ (fig and ax in your case). Therefore, if you want to plot on that specific subplot you have to specify it when you call the plot function (this is done with `ax=ax`). Otherwise a new figure will be generated. If you want to avoid ambiguities you could call your subplot differently, _e.g._ `fig, ax0 = plt.subplots(...)` and then `r5_base.plot(ax=ax0,..)`